# Weather API for email?

Tags: weather, cgi-bin, weather-api

Is there a way to display current weather conditions for the recipient of an email?
I have seen some sites use a CGI bin type link but do not know how this is implemented. 
I am actually looking for anything that will work or to find out if it is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the obvious way of using some javascript (http://blog.exacttarget.com/blog/email-design-4/email-design-tip-of-the-week-javascript-in-email) or iframes (http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/3219/do-iframes-work-in-email/) does not seem to be terribly likely to succeed.

One method that might work is to embed an image that is hosted on your servers which is dynamically created and populated w/the weather you'd like each user to see.

Comment: Cool thanks ya javascript will not work in large email blast engines. I have not looked into iframe stuff. (not even really sure how that would work but i will check out. Dynamic image might be cool to.. I will have to look into that as well. Thanks for your help.